# How to remove image boundary in libreOffice Writer

Tags: libreoffice

In the following screenshot you can see an outline around the image.

[image: image with outline in libreoffice]

I need to remove that outline and I don't have any idea how to do it!

Comment: Does that line exist in print preview?

Comment: Thank you! problem solved! this lines not exist in print. then no need to worry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the following screenshots, where the same image is put twice in the text, using different settings.

Selecting the right image, then right clicking on it, then selecting *Properties...*, you get the *Properties* window where there are two things to notice:

1. *Wrap* → *Spacing* defines the blank space between image object and text.

   [image: example]
2. *Borders* → *Spacing to Contents* defines the blank space between the image border and the image

   [image: screenshot]

Putting all those spacings to zero, leaves no blank space between the image and the text.

You can also try adjusting all other border attributes to your needs.

Answer (score 6):

Go to *View*, uncheck the option *Text Boundaries* and you are done.

[image]

Comment: This answer should solve exactly the OP's problem. +1! It would be really improved it if you could [edit] it to also add a screenshot of the *View* menu.